# How to set up plugin downloads over SSL?

Tags: sbt

I have a SBT project that uses the [sbt-start-script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) plugin.  When I run SBT, the plugin jar is downloaded over unsecured HTTP instead of HTTPS:

> downloading http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.10.0/jars/sbt-start-script.jar ...

I want to use the `https` version of the repo instead (which I can browse to manually), but I can't figure out how get SBT to use it.

My `project/plugins.sbt` looks like this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.10.0")
```

I tried adding the `https` version to the SBT properties' `[repositories]` section and also tried adding it to the `resolvers` list, but SBT always uses the `http` version of the repo.

Does `addSbtPlugin` add the repo automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Create `~/.sbt/repositories` with a https version or create a repositories file of different non-default name and run `sbt` with `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` and `-Dsbt.repository.config=path-to-the-repositories-file`.

Let's start with the default build definition - no additional setup but what comes with sbt itself.

`show fullResolvers` to know the external resolvers for automatically managed dependencies - there are three resolvers (formatting is mine to ease reading).

```
➜  https-repositories  xsbt
...
> show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(
Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )),
FileRepository(local,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)),
public: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

[Command Line Options](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options) says:

- `sbt.override.build.repos` If `true`, repositories configured in a build definition are ignored and the repositories configured for the launcher are used instead. See `sbt.repository.config` and the sbt launcher documentation.
- `sbt.repository.config` A file containing the repositories to use for the launcher. The format is the same as a `[repositories]` section for a sbt launcher configuration file. This setting is typically used in conjuction with setting `sbt.override.build.repos` to true (see previous row and the sbt launcher documentation).

That means that when sbt finds `~/.sbt/repositories` with `[repositories]` inside they will become the resolvers for sbt.

Create `~/.sbt/repositories` with the following content:

```
[repositories]
httpsInstead: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/,[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

As you may have noticed, the file *solely* defines a https version of the repository in question.

`reload` the session (or start it over) and do `show fullResolvers`.

```
➜  https-repositories  ls ~/.sbt/repositories
/Users/jacek/.sbt/repositories
➜  https-repositories  xsbt
...
> show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(
Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )),
URLRepository(httpsInstead,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)))
```

There are two resolvers now!

Let's use the `sbt.*` options - `sbt.override.build.repos` and `sbt.repository.config`.

```
➜  https-repositories  ls ~/.sbt/my_repositories
/Users/jacek/.sbt/my_repositories
➜  https-repositories  ls ~/.sbt/repositories*
zsh: no matches found: /Users/jacek/.sbt/repositories*
➜  https-repositories  SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.override.build.repos=false -Dsbt.repository.config=/Users/jacek/.sbt/my_repositories" xsbt
...
> show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(
Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )),
URLRepository(httpsInstead,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)))
```

There are two resolvers again.

It appears that it doesn't change much with `sbt.override.build.repos=true`.

```
➜  https-repositories  SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config=/Users/jacek/.sbt/my_repositories" xsbt
...
> show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(
Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )),
URLRepository(httpsInstead,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)))
```

What's interesting is that with `sbt.override.build.repos=true` the resolvers change for sbt project builds.

This is a sample `build.sbt` with an imaginary repository:

```
resolvers += "build.sbt" at "http://my.repository.com"
```

The first session is with `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=false`:

```
➜  https-repositories  SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.override.build.repos=false -Dsbt.repository.config=/Users/jacek/.sbt/my_repositories" xsbt
...
> show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(
Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )),
URLRepository(httpsInstead,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)),
build.sbt: http://my.repository.com)
```

Another session with `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true`:

```
➜  https-repositories  SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config=/Users/jacek/.sbt/my_repositories" xsbt
...
> show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(
Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )),
URLRepository(httpsInstead,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)))
```

Comment: What if my build.sbt lists other repos?  Is there a way to just disable the implicitly-added `http://repo.scala-sbt.org` one without disabling all of them?

Comment: I think that would require a command that would be executed at startup replacing all the repos to their `https` counterparts - I don't think there's anything available in sbt out of the box, but the pieces are.

Comment: Just edited my answer and it appears that `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` is pretty powerful (beyond my initial understanding!) Does this help?

Comment: I gave up and decided to just use `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` and include all extra repos in the `.properties` file instead of in a build file.